# exsheets and \PrintSolutionsTF Question

Tags: exsheets

Am I missing something very basic with the `exsheets` package and its `\PrintSolutionsTF` command?

I figured that if I set `\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}` I would get 4 (this works) and for `\SetupExSheets{solution/print=false}`, I'd get 5, but I get a blank here instead.

What's going on?

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{solution/print=false}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
\(2+2=\underline{\hspace{1cm}}\)
\end{question}

\begin{solution}
\PrintSolutionsTF{4 is a true answer}{5 is a false answer}
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Never mind, I just figured out that I'm not supposed to put `\PrintSolutionsTF{}{}` in a solution environment. I'll be back soon, though, with a more complex question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Inside a `{solution}` environment `\PrintSolutionsTF{true}{false}` *always* gives `true`. Outside a `{solution}` environment it depends on the value of the option `solution/print`.

In your example if you have

```
\begin{solution}
  \PrintSolutionsTF{true}{false}
\end{solution}
```

but say `\SetupExSheets{solution/print=false}` then the *whole* solution environment is *not* printed.

If you additionally ad `\printsolutions` for a list of solutions then you'll get the `true` value regardless what value `solution/print` has: as I said initially: inside a solution it is always true.

PS: I'll correct this in the manual. The current description (v0.19 and earlier) is wrong.